# Having trouble mirroring a website

Tags: download, website, file-sharing

Okay, so I'm trying to mirror a website, obviously.

And I'm I having trouble downloading a few files, I was just curious if these files are "important". I have used both File2HD.com and HTTRACK to mirror the site. Let me just go ahead and say this, HTTRACK did a WAY better job at getting the files for me. However, no matter what program I use, I always end up with the same errors saying "unable to download the following files:"

(Missing File 1) /css/owl.carousel.css

(Missing File 2) /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

(Missing File 3) /fonts/SEGOEUIL.ttf

(Missing File 4) /Popover

The site is still functional and when I put two windows of the real site and my site side by side, I see no difference and it's functional just like the real site. So, my question is, is "/css/owl.carousel.css" and "/Popover" important? Do I need to get those files? If so, How can I get them?!! (Without asking the site owner "Hey, can I have your site files?) LOL :(

Comment: No, it's not copyrighted. Is owl.carousel.css and popover important?

Comment: It's in testing stages, it's just a single page for Design Idea Purposes Only

Comment: Perhaps, but I am the owner of the design. It is my design, someone else used my design for their site.

Comment: I created a photoshop version of the design, and my former partner, who knows how to build websites, used it.

Comment: i need 20 points to chat?

Comment: apparantly. head over here then: http://insomnia247.nl/page/chat and we'll talk about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that those files returns a `404` or `Page Not Found` error, which means they don't exist, which means you don't need them.